# Detecting image width via JavaScript when maxWidth is used

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, image, width

Consider this code:

```
var img = new Image();

img.onload = function() {
    console.log(this.width);
};

img.src = 'http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/9/9a/Gull_portrait_ca_usa.jpg/800px-Gull_portrait_ca_usa.jpg';

document.body.appendChild(img);
```

This will print out the image width (800) correctly. But if I apply a max-width using CSS:

```
img {max-width: 400px}
```

Test case: http://jsfiddle.net/MSjnM/

The JS code above will print out `400` instead. That is a bit confusing, as one would think that the `width` attribute represents the original image width, not the computed width.

Now to something even more confusing, if I append the image in the onload event after the width detection I get a different result:

```
var img = new Image();

img.onload = function() {
    console.log(this.width);
    document.body.appendChild(img);
};

img.src = 'http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/9/9a/Gull_portrait_ca_usa.jpg/800px-Gull_portrait_ca_usa.jpg';
```

Test case: http://jsfiddle.net/MSjnM/2/

This will print out `800` instead, even though the CSS has applied. I assume it’s because the image is appended **after** I detected the width and that the max-width will be applied as soon as the image is inserted into the DOM.

OK, so if I want to get the original image size, no matter when or if the `IMG` element is inserted in the DOM or whatever CSS styles has been applied, how would I do that fail-safe?

Comment: using Fx11 and Op11.61 both your fiddle print "400".

Comment: @FabrizioCalderan I was testing in Chrome, but that is even more alarming...

Comment: OK I changed the code slightly to get the same effect across browsers, thanks Fabrizio.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For me:
in IE9, Opera, Safari(PC), FF and chrome the [**naturalWidth/naturalHeight**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/gg593099%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)-properties return the desired values

[**http://jsfiddle.net/MSjnM/5/**](http://jsfiddle.net/MSjnM/5/)

Comment: nice, +1: in which IE version is supported?

Comment: IE9 as I wrote. In IE8 width returns 800 for me.

Answer (score 2):

Load the image independently into a new Image object and get the width there:

```
var img = new Image();
img.src = 'http://placehold.it/350x150'
console.log(img.width);
```

Comment: This is not reliable in Safari. Also, it doesn’t work if the image is present in the DOM and a max-width has been applied.

Comment: Sidenote: the image should be in cache by now, so no extra request / performance loss here.

Comment: @David Thought: is it only unreliable in Safari because you have a CSS rule making all `<img>`s have a max-width? Surely even if it is applying the CSS rule to an `Image()` object not in the DOM, so long as you can make the CSS rule more specific, then there won't be a problem?